# connect to amazon server that allows only one ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, wifi, ip-address

I have an amazon server (AWS) with a security group that blocks all the ip addresses except mine.
The problem is that I use my computer through different wifi hotspots so my ip address often changes. Is there a way to connect my computer to my server with always the same ip address?

Comment: A VPN, or just update the security group.

Comment: If IP address is changeable then it is tricky to set the security group up, it basically requires you to update it often. Consider another authentication mechanism not based on IP address white list.

Comment: I don't want to update the rules of my security group each time my ip address changes, so I am going to look into the VPN solution... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an amazon server (AWS) with a security group that blocks all the ip addresses except mine.

Nothing wrong with that. Pretty good actually.

> The problem is that I use my computer through different wifi hotspots so my ip address often changes.

So don't actually have your own static ip-address? How did you manage the above then???

> Is there a way to connect my computer to my server with always the same ip address?

Set up a VPN server with less stringent or no IP-based access controls, establish a VPN connection to that and then you will always connect to your servers from the IP-address of your VPN server.

Comment: I think the VPN solution is exactly what I need... I am going to look into that now. In fact I use the wifi hotspot of my android phone to get the internet on my computer. Each time I stop and restart the wifi hotspot on my phone, then the ip address on my computer changes... I couldn't find any option to have a static ip address.

Comment: Just created a VPN in amazon. I can now access my server using the VPN ip address. But why did amazon create a new EC2 instance for that? It's going to cost me more!